# Onomatopoeia for a kettle

Tags: onomatopoeia

When the water is hot enough, what is the sound made by the kettle?

Is `Choo-choo` correct ?

Comment: *Choo-choo* is the sound made by a children's steam train and/or its whistle. Not sure about teapots, I don't recall mine making any noise whatsoever as it just sits there... do you mean a kettle of some kind?

Comment: @ProfYaffle You're right! I was thinking of a kettle. Question corrected. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Whiiiiiiieeee***

> - sound from a tea kettle.

From ([Onomatopoeia Book](http://joannamarple.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Onomatopoeia-Book.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

Stove-top kettles generally *whistle* to indicate the water has boiled—indeed, they're often called "whistling kettles", to distinguish them from electric jug kettles.

Electric kettles don't usually make a recognisable noise when the water has boiled, they just switch themselves off.

Comment: `whistle` is an onomatopoeia?

Comment: I guess not, technically. Though depending on the exact whistling noise, it's not far off.

Comment: "Whistle" *is* onomatopoeia. Source: etymonline.com

Comment: it's from Swedish "vissla".  It does not sound at all onomatopaic to me.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a very good onomatopoeia, but there are lots of examples of onomatopoeia that don't really sound that much like the thing in question.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably have to describe the water or steam versus the boiling kettle itself - the *whoosh* and the *bubble*, the *grumbling* of the water, the *glugging*, *splashing* stream as you pour it into the cup. Or somesuch.

Comment: I was thinking about the whistling... one word at a time! Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be *scream*, *screech*, or *shriek*. [Ngram suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=screaming+kettle%2Cscreeching+kettle%2Cwhistling+kettle%2Cshrieking+kettle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscreaming%20kettle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhistling%20kettle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrieking%20kettle%3B%2Cc0) that describing a kettle as *screaming* or *shrieking* is not unusual, though less common than *whistling*, while *screeching* is rare.